# how do I get my ajax data into a php array?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following data in a JS script:

```
$("#holdSave").live('click', function () {
    var arr = {};
    var cnt = 0;

    $('#holdTable tbody tr').each(function () {
        arr[cnt] = {
            buyer: $(this).find('#tableBuyer').html(),
            sku: $(this).find('#tableSku').html(),
            isbn: $(this).find('#tableISBN').html(),
            cost: $(this).find('#tableCost').val(),
            csmt: $(this).find('#tableConsignment').val(),
            hold: $(this).find('#tableHold').val()
        };
        cnt++;
    }); //end of holdtable tbody function
    console.log(arr);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "holdSave.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            data: arr
        },

        success: function (data) {

        } // end of success function

    }); // end of ajax call

}); // end of holdSave event
```

I need to send this to a php file for updating the db and emailing that the update was done.  My console.log(arr); shows the objects when I run it in firebug, but I can't get any of the information on the php side.  Here is what I have for php code:

```
$data = $_POST['data']; 

print_r($data); die;
```

At this point I am just trying to verify that there is info being sent over.  My print_r($data); returns nothing.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Use the appropriate tools. In this case, Firebug, fiddler2, Developer Tools, etc .. then monitor the network requests. Then, if there *is* something sent, simplify the question *only* the relevant PHP stuff that deals with the title and post *what* is sent ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType: "json"` means you are expecting to retrieve json data in your request not what you are sending.

If you want to send a json string to be retrieved by `$_POST['data']` use

```
data: {data: JSON.stringify(arr)},
```

Comment: If I use your suggestion, do I need to then use json_decode() in the php file? ie $data = json_decode($_POST['data']?

Comment: @Jim Yes, I don't think there is any method that wouldn't require it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` methods

Answer (score 0):

Use the next way:

```
data = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'};

$.post('holdSave.php', data, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Note: haven't tested it, make sure to look for parse errors.